# HTML5 possible to jump to footer from anchor tag?

Tags: html

I want to create a link that jumps to the footer when clicked. What would such an anchor tag look like?

I have html like so:

```
<a href="?????">Footer</a>
....some html...
<footer>
  some footer text
</footer>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the only possible way to achieve this without the use of javascript is

```
 <a href="#my-footer">Footer</a>
 ....some html...
 <footer id="my-footer">
   some footer text
</footer>
```

Comment: I feared that is the case. This isn't what I was hoping for, but I believe your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you could go with this:

```
<script>
function scrollDown() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("footer").offset().top}, 200);
}
</script>

<a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="javascript:scrollDown();">Click</a>
```

This would give you a nice animation instead of just jumping there.